# Excel-VBA MultiPage: move/reorder/index pages at runtime?

Tags: vba, excel, userform, multipage

I'm working on a little Excel-VBA GUI/Form for the user to read and write data from/to an .ini file. The UserForm has a MultiPage in which the user creates pages at runtime and each page will represent an ini section. Furthermore, these sections are also indexed in a master section for further processing: at this point I'm looping through the MultiPage pages to create this index. Problem is, the user needs to be able to change the order of this index. Now, is it possible to move the pages within a MultiPage at runtime? I was thinking something to the effect of

```
Me.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Index = i + 1
```

but obviously that doesn't work. Alternatively, is there a way I can pass a before:= or anything similar to Multipage.Pages.Add to work around it?
If none of this works, I think I'll create a seperate ListBox control with MoveUp/Down buttons. Open for any better solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a `UserForm` that looks like this:

[image]

Then you can include the sample code below to move the order of the `Page` items of the `MultiPage`:

```
Option Explicit

'moves selected page to left
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim pag As MSForms.Page
    Dim lngPageCount As Long

    ' get reference to page
    Set pag = Me.MultiPage1.SelectedItem
    ' get number of pages in multipage
    lngPageCount = Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
    ' check if trying to go left beyond first page and put to end
    ' otherwise decrement pages position in multipage
    If pag.Index = 0 Then
        pag.Index = lngPageCount - 1
    Else
        pag.Index = pag.Index - 1
    End If

    ' update caption
    Me.Label1.Caption = pag.Name & " is at index " & pag.Index

End Sub

'moves selected page to right
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim pag As MSForms.Page
    Dim lngPageCount As Long

    ' get reference to page
    Set pag = Me.MultiPage1.SelectedItem
    ' get number of pages in multipage
    lngPageCount = Me.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
    ' check if trying to go right beyond number of pages and put to start
    ' otherwise increment pages position in multipage
    If pag.Index = lngPageCount - 1 Then
        pag.Index = 0
    Else
        pag.Index = pag.Index + 1
    End If

    ' update caption
    Me.Label1.Caption = pag.Name & " is at index " & pag.Index

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Robin, perfect. So Page.Index does exist, I just had to declare the page as a separate object first, correct? Since my pages are created at runtime, I had to modify to code a bit and put in a class. I'll post the solution in an edit to the question, hope that's proper procedure here. Thanks.

Comment: Hi - glad it helped. You can post an answer to your own question if you've got a code update that solves your problem. That's probably a better option rather than change the question.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie nice :)

Answer (score 1):

For anybody looking for this in the future, here's the complete solution using Robin's code (Thanks!), but put in a Class for the pages created at runtime. I'm only pasting the relevant code to this question, the CopyPage procedure can also be called by the user to add pages during runtime. Now the user can also move them left and right between pages 2 (index 1) and n.

In my main module:

```
Public arrLeftButton() As New CButton
Public arrRightButton() As New CButton
```

In my CButton Class Module:

```
Option Explicit
Public WithEvents CopyButton As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents DeleteButton As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents MoveLeft As MSForms.CommandButton
Public WithEvents MoveRight As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub MoveLeft_Click()
    Dim pag As MSForms.Page
    Dim lngPageCount As Long
    Set pag = UFmodproject.MultiPage1.SelectedItem
    lngPageCount = UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
    If pag.Index > 1 Then
        pag.Index = pag.Index - 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MoveRight_Click()
    Dim pag As MSForms.Page
    Dim lngPageCount As Long
    Set pag = UFmodproject.MultiPage1.SelectedItem
    lngPageCount = UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Pages.Count
    If pag.Index < lngPageCount - 1 Then
        pag.Index = pag.Index + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

And my UserForm_Initialize:

```
Private Sub userform_initialize()
    ReDim Preserve arrLeftButton(1 To 1)
    ReDim Preserve arrRightButton(1 To 1)
    Set arrLeftButton(1).MoveLeft = MultiPage1.Pages(1).Controls("MoveLeft1")
    Set arrRightButton(1).MoveRight = MultiPage1.Pages(1).Controls("MoveRight1")
    For i = 2 To GetINIString("Project", "NumberOfShipmentTypes", strINIPATH)
        Call FormControls.CopyPage
    Next
End Sub
```

Yet in another standard module, so it can be called from elsewhere too:

```
Sub CopyPage()
    Dim l As Double, r As Double
    Dim Ctrl As Control
    Dim newCtrl As Object
    Dim pCount As Long
    pCount = UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Pages.Count

    '[...add pages and copy all controls]

    For Each newCtrl In UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Pages(pCount).Controls
        If Left(newCtrl.Name, Len(newCtrl.Name) - 1) = "MoveLeft" Then
            ReDim Preserve arrLeftButton(1 To pCount)
            Set arrLeftButton(pCount).MoveLeft = newCtrl
        End If
        If Left(newCtrl.Name, Len(newCtrl.Name) - 1) = "MoveRight" Then
            ReDim Preserve arrRightButton(1 To pCount)
            Set arrRightButton(pCount).MoveRight = newCtrl
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```