# Excel-VBA: Set Userfom Control.Name at runtime (runtime error 382)

Tags: vba, excel, userform, multipage

I'm working on a little Excel-VBA GUI/Form for the user to read and write data from/to an .ini file. One of the `UserForms` has a `MultiPage` item for which the user creates pages at runtime and [after help from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43158667/excel-vba-multipage-move-reorder-index-pages-at-runtime), they can also move the pages around. Because the control properties are used to write data to the .ini file, the controls must be named correctly, that is for my purpose, among other things, in line with the relevant `MultiPage.Value`. I added the following to the MoveLeft/Right methods and I get an error saying I *cannot change the `Control.Name` property at runtime (382).*

```
For i = 1 To UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1
    For Each Ctrl In UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Controls
        If TypeOf Ctrl Is MSForms.TextBox Then
            Ctrl.Name = Left(Ctrl.Name, Len(Ctrl.Name) - 1) & i
        End If
    Next
Next
```

The strange thing is, I'm doing pretty much the same thing when copying a page, and that doesn't produce any errors:

```
For Each newCtrl In UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Pages(pCount).Controls
    For Each Ctrl In UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Pages(UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Value).Controls
        If (Ctrl.Left = newCtrl.Left And Ctrl.Top = newCtrl.Top) Then
            newCtrl.Name = Left(Ctrl.Name, Len(Ctrl.Name) - 1) & pCount
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    '[bunch of other code...]
Next
```

What could be the error here? For what it's worth, I tried `Dim Ctrl as Object` and `Dim Ctrl as Control`, both work when copying but none of them when I only try to set the `Control.Name` property.  Furthermore, the code to copy a page is in a standard module and called from a class module. The new code to rename the controls is in the class module. I tried moving it to a standard module like the other, but to no avail.

EDIT:
I thought I had figured it out and that the error wasn't that it couldn't change the property at runtime, but it seemed that an ambiguous name is detected when the Control.Name property is set to its own value. But I was still getting errors when I tried to move a page to Value 1. Since I still seemed to have ambiguous names I ended up with the following to test:

```
Sub SetNames()
    Dim Ctrl As Object
    Dim Ctrl2 As Object
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Name As String
    For i = 1 To UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Pages.Count - 1
        For Each Ctrl In UFmodproject.MultiPage1.Pages(i).Controls
            If Int(Right(Ctrl.Name, 1)) <> i Then
                For Each Ctrl2 In UFmodproject.Controls
                    If Ctrl2.Name = Left(Ctrl.Name, Len(Ctrl.Name) - 1) & i Then
                        Ctrl2.Name = Left(Ctrl.Name, Len(Ctrl.Name) - 1) & i + 4
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                Ctrl.Name = Left(Ctrl.Name, Len(Ctrl.Name) - 1) & i
            End If
        Next Ctrl
    Next i
End Sub
```

but I still kept getting the same error, but when I checked for the object with the supposedly used name in the immediate window it confirms the object doesn't exist. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I did a little testing, seems you can only change the `Name` of controls created at runtime (eg `Set tb = UFmodproject.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")  tb.Name = "NewName" ` works).  Can't change `Name` of existing controls on the form

Comment: Thanks Chris, but then why does it work 80%  of the time for me? See my code to copy the page, I didn't get any errors, and on the new SetNames() I only get the error on some controls.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my point: there is a difference between controls you place on the form in the VBA IDE, and controls you create with code (by using `<something>.Controls.Add`  In my testing for the former you cannot change Names, for the latter you can.  My suspicion is raised by your comment in the OP that _`the user creates pages at runtime `_

Comment: @Chris, All of these pages and controls are created by code at runtime, except page1 where the controls are copied from. And the code does work, but just not when I want to set the names for the controls on MultiPage1. Did you look at the link to my previous question?  I'm sure it must have something to do with ambiguity.

Comment: based on that I would expect you would be able to change all the control's names _except_those on page 1.  Can you confirm wether or not that is the case?

Comment: Why use the control names? Can't you just either `a` use the `tag` property or `b` if handling the events with a custom object pass an additional param to the object?

Comment: @Chris, my apologies, seems I misread your comment. I thought you were saying the exact opposite, sorry. So yes, correct, I cannot change the control.names that were created in the editor (page1). Now I tried to copy the page and remove the template page, but it doesn't let me do that either. Is it possible that I also cannot remove controls that were created in the IDE?

Comment: Thanks @SWa, I was thinking about that too.. the .tag property is already in use to store .ini key values, I'm using the names to address the controls to add them to arrays to set the right events, for example. But then maybe I'll have to go and create all the controls at runtime, create an object array for all controls and then add properties to them...?